# Passport Authentication With Marionette Application

Tags: ajax, marionette, passport.js, passport-local

So the passport authentication works very well with express app. I have a marionette app, how do I use passport for authentication with marionette?

I am not exert coder by any means, to start simply, I am running the node-authentication on localhost-8080 which basically uses passport authentication. It does all thats in tutorial so it works great!

Now I have Marionette App in ( I am running locally on apache) which has index.html/login.html. Currently for most simple connection, I captured the form submit and tried to make AJAX call (POST) to login page running on the server (localhost :8080), not sure if this is a right way as my authentication server needs to be up all the time. But anyhow the first problem is it is hitting GET method even though I have specified the POST. First is how do I ensure that it only hits POST on server, second is how do I pass the require data to this for authentication ( form data).

I will ask next question later (you guessed it will ask :) - how to use session in marionette), first I need to get the first hurdle to authenticate.

Please let me know the right way of if I am on right path what do i do?

Comment: I am able to perform the authentication, i think it was redirection in authenticate (success) causing to issue the GET. but is resolved now. Now my next step is to get the logged in user details in index page. still not able to figure out, anyone got idea to share?

Comment: I added another method to get the logged in user from server program (instead of checking the cookies) and now able to get the logged on user details on client page (marionette).